# Why does itertools.product(*empty_list) return an empty tuple inside a list?

Tags: python

With `empty_list = []`, if we call `list(itertools.product(empty_list))`, we get the expected empty list, `[]`.

However, `list(itertools.product(*empty_list))` returns `[()]` (an empty tuple inside a list).

How is there anything to unpack, if `empty_list` is empty? Does this kind of behavior happen with other functions?

Comment: Note that `list(itertools.product(*empty_list))` is the same as `list(itertools.product())`, which also displays this behaviour.

Comment: Aha! So unpacking an empty list is like calling the function with no arguments?

Comment: Of course. That's what unpacking does. Turning an iterable into arguments is the whole point of argument unpacking.

Comment: Looking back it seems so obvious now :/